# Logisim ROM Output not matching address input

Tags: logisim

I'm getting this really weird problem when trying to use the built in ROM chip in Logisim. First off, even though I specified a 16-bit data bit width, the ROM only stores 4 bits per address (isn't this supposed to be 16 per address?).
When I specify an address (input), instead of displaying the output 4 bits, it seems to display some bits in some places and not in others. It's a little hard to describe because each time I switch the address I get a weird output that I don't expect and I can't figure out what methodology the ROM is following for displaying output. Here is one situation in the picture below where the input address is 15, and the output is a 0001000100010001. The address 15 currently stores 1111, and I have no idea where the zeros come from and why the 1's are spaced out like that[image]. I must be misunderstanding something about this. If there are only 4 bits per 15 bit address, how does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values stored in the ROM are being displayed in hexadecimal, not binary. Each hexadecimal digit is equivalent to four bits, and the hexadecimal digits `0` and `1` are equivalent to binary `0000` and `0001`.

Comment: I understand that it's in hexidecimal, however that doesn't explain why the output is 0001000100010001 and why there are only 4 bits per address.

Comment: What you're looking at are four hexadecimal digits for each address, not "4 bits".

Comment: No that's not what I'm talking about

Comment: Let me spell this out. The value you have entered at the address `000f` (hex) is `1111` (hex). This is a 16-bit value with the binary representation `0001 0001 0001 0001`.

Comment: so you're saying that the value stored in address 000f is 0001000100010001?

Comment: ohhhh wait Ok I figured out what my error is. You meant that the ROM contents are in hexadecimal. I thought those were binary my bad.